# how to test regex in javascript in if statement

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check this regex on a variable in if statement of javascript

```
var re = any valid regular expression that will check if value contains a-zA-Z or any special character expcept . ;
```

as here

```
if(selling_price=="" || selling_price==" " || retail_price==" " || retail_price=="" || re.test(selling_price) || re.test(retail_price))
```

selling_price and and retail_price both variables needed to be checked with this regex.(please suggest regex)

Comment: `re.test(selling_price)`. You may also want to `trim` your strings to simplify your tests for empty values.

Comment: It also appears that you are using some sort of negative validation (I'm guessing, since the expression is false if the price contains any digits). I think you'll find that it often makes more semantic sense to verify that the input meets an expectation, rather than doesn't deviate in a predefined way. Just make sure to use `^...$` so as to validate the entire input string.

Comment: @DavidHedlund  i cant think of any reason for down voting the question if i cant answer it

Comment: I did answer your question (with comments). I did not downvote it. I can think of reasons why your questions received downvotes, however, as it's not very clear from your question what you want to achieve.

Comment: don't be angry. sorry! you made two comments and I thought it was someone else who made the first comment.please check the question again i have modified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.test(string)` may be your answer, but if you want to replace :

```
if(selling_price=="" || selling_price==" " || retail_price==" " || retail_price=="")
```

by that:

```
if(re.test(selling_price) || re.test(retail_price)
```

it won't work as `selling_price==""`do not correspond to your regexp 
you still need to check for empty results

Comment: Thanks for your answer